# unprivileged SSH sessions timeout but a session that has been su'd (to root) stays alive

Tags: ssh, timeout

From Windows-10, I use MobaXterm to SSH log in to a Fedora-38 machine remotely with unprivileged account 'mike' and typically establish a second session that I su to privileged 'root' account so I don't have to sudo and provide a password every time.

The unprivileged connection will get timed out (with 60-second KeepAlive on the SSHD machine) even if I run top to keep it active, but the su'd session usually won't get timed out nearly as quickly.  Particularly interesting: if I su to mike from mike, that session will still timeout.

### Why? and What can I do to stop the unprivileged sessions from timing out?

I have since learned that privilege has nothing to do with it. Wait a little while and root will lose his connection to the SSH server machine too. For reasons I still haven't figured out, the W-10 machine's LAN I/F (192.168.0.44) can't see the Linux SSH server, so I'm stuck with the WiFi connection (on 192.168.0.40), which CAN see the Linux machine, but that connection keeps resetting (perhaps by MobaXterm) after relatively brief sessions (a couple of minutes), where a week ago, SSH connections lasted for hours.

I have a short keep alive period set on the SSHD server (now 60 seconds) and the MobaXterm keep alive check box checked too.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you get a specific error message when it times out?  If so, can you copy and paste it as a code block so we can see the output?

Comment: "Network error: Software caused connection abort"
though I just got one on a su root session, so privilege may be irrelevant.  Presumably, software means MobaXterm?